# $(document).ready(function() - don't work

Tags: jquery

I am using Rails & jQuery.

Here is HTML which I get:

```
<head>
  <title>Some</title>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1305699774" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   alert("2");
   $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("1");
      ....
```

When I am refreshing the window I get only one alert message ("2").
Why I didn't get second alert message?

[image]

Comment: Did your browser give some error?

Comment: Check the console for errors that say `$` isn't defined. If you find one, check you're including the correct file.

Comment: not enough info to answer. It would be easy if you can post your full code. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: have u closed with `});`

Comment: Chrome console contains "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'"

Comment: I have added screenshot of Chrome debugger.

Comment: Are you using any other frameworks like MooTools?

Comment: `$().ready` gives the same error ? Also you have both jQuery and Prototype loaded

Comment: Yes, $().ready geves the same error: Cannot call method 'ready' of undefined

Comment: Thanks, if I remove all other libraries the problem disappear.

Comment: See http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries for information on getting jQuery and Prototype to cohabitate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have included `prototype`, which also defines `$`.
So use `jQuery()` instead of `$` and run `jQuery` in [.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode